# Caret's train() & resamples() reverses sensitivity/specificity for GLM

Tags: r, r-caret, glm, resampling

The documentation for the `glm()` function states, regarding a factor response variable, that

> the first level denotes failure and all others success.

I assume caret's `train()` function calls `glm()` under the hood when using `method = 'glm'`, and therefore the same applies.

So in order to produce an interpretable model that is consistent with other models (**i.e. the coefficients correspond to a `success` event**), I must follow this convention.

The problem is that, even though glm(), and thus caret's `train()` function treats the second level factor as a success, **caret's `resamples` function (and `$resample` variable) still treat the first level as `success` / `positive`, and therefore `sensitivity` and `specificity` are the opposite of what they should be if i want to use `resamples()` to compare against other models..**

Example:

```
install.packages('ISLR')
library('ISLR')
summary(Default)
levels(Default$default) # 'yes' is second level on factor
glm_model <- glm(default ~ ., family = "binomial", data = Default)
summary(glm_model)

train_control <- trainControl(
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
    classProbs = TRUE,
    method = 'repeatedcv',
    number = 5,
    repeats = 5,
    verboseIter = FALSE,
    savePredictions = TRUE)
set.seed(123)
caret_model <- train(default ~ ., data = Default, method = 'glm', metric='ROC', preProc=c('nzv', 'center', 'scale', 'knnImpute'), trControl = train_control)
summary(caret_model)
caret_model # shows Sens of ~0.99 and Spec of ~0.32
caret_model$resample # shows same, but for each fold/repeat; by now, resamples are already the opposite of what they should be, which will propagate to resamples() method, no way to specify positive/success class in train()?

confusionMatrix(data = predict(caret_model, Default), reference = Default$default, positive = 'Yes') # once I set 'Yes' as positive class, the true sensitivity and specificity are calculated, but no way to do this for resamples()?
```

I can see the correct sens/spec in `confusionMatrix` with `positive = 'Yes'` but what is the solution for `resamples()` so that I can accurately compare it against other models?

Answer (score 0):

The following will invert the sensitivity:

```
temp <- Default
temp$default <- fct_relevel(temp$default, "Yes")
levels(temp$default)
levels(Default$default)

caret_model <- train(relevel(default, ref = "Yes") ~ ., data = temp, method = 'glm', metric='ROC', preProc=c('nzv', 'center', 'scale', 'knnImpute'), trControl = train_control)
summary(caret_model)
caret_model
```

Based on page 272 of the book *Applied Predictive Modeling*;

*The glm() function models the probability of the second factor
level, so the function relevel() is used to temporarily reverse the
factors levels.*